# Trouble with passing const reference object as parameter, VS debugger reports 'left of '.getXCoord' must have calls/struct/union'

Tags: c++, class, constants

In my header file, I've defined the Point class, constructs a (x, y) coordinate point, contains a few getter and setter member functions, and contains a toDistance member function, which returns the distance between two points.

```
class Point
{
private:
    double x_coord;
    double y_coord;
public:
    Point(double x, double y);
    Point();
    void setXCoord(double);
    void setYCoord(double);
    double getXCoord();
    double getYCoord();
    double toDistance(const Point*);
};
```

Here are the member functions (of interest) in the implementation file:

```
double Point::getXCoord() {
    return x_coord;
}
double Point::getYCoord() {
    return y_coord;
}

double Point::toDistance(const Point *P2) {

    double p1_x = getXCoord();
    double p1_y = getYCoord();
    double p2_x = P2.getXCoord();
    double p2_y = P2.getYCoord();

    double x_distance = p2_x - p1_x;
    double y_distance = p2_y - p1_y;

    double distance = sqrt(pow(x_distance, 2) + pow(y_distance, 2));

    return distance;
```

}

When running with test data, VS returns the error

> left of '.getXCoord' must have calls/struct/union'

for the lines

> double p2_x = P2.getXCoord();

and

> double p2_y = P2.getYCoord();

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried `P2->getXCoord()`?

Comment: what type does P2 have?

Comment: @W.F. I did, and I get 'the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "Point::getXCoord"'.

grigor, it's an object (if I'm doing this right).

Comment: @ehh123 as grigor pointed you also need to change the `getXCoord` specifier to const

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, P2 is const reference. In that case you're not allowed to call non-const functions. You need to make your getter functions const (maybe also the toDistance function). You'd change your functions like this:

```
double getXCoord() const;
```

etc. Also make sure to change that in the implementation.

If P2 is a const pointer (not a reference) then in addition you need to modify your calls to be like `P2->getXCoord()` etc.

Comment: @grigor, I made your recommended changes and updated the two getter functions and the toDistance function to const functions. Now, I get the following error message:

'double Point::toDistance(const Point *) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Point' to 'const Point *'

Comment: How are you passing your argument to `toDistance`? If you're passing a point, let say p, then you need to put `&` in front, i.e. `toDistance(&p)`.